# Rewrite rule to only redirect if not specific keywords are there

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am writing specific rules that after my Base URL  any keyword will be  redirected to folder subdomains/
for e.g   www.xyz.com/hdaCompany will redirect to  www.xyz.com/subdomains/hdaCompany .
But i want exception for few keywords for not to redirect to subdomains but there own rules like search-result .
but problem it is routing everything to subdomains thus search-result url not working  Here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule    ^search-result/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?$    search-result.php?BtnSearch=$1&SearchTerm=$2&Location=$3&Rating=$4&Keyword=$5     
        RewriteRule    ^search-result/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$    search-result.php?BtnSearch=$1&SearchTerm=$2&Location=$3   
        RewriteRule    ^search-result/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$    search-result.php?BtnSearch=$1&SearchTerm=$2 
        RewriteRule    ^special-deal/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?$    special-deal.php?BtnSearch=$1&SearchTerm=$2&Location=$3&Rating=$4&Keyword=$5  
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomains/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A2592000
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^/data/*.php">
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

That was pretty simple ... Here is how i did it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search-result.* 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/special-deal.* 
    RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ subdomains/$1

    RewriteRule    ^search-result/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?$    search-result.php?BtnSearch=$1&SearchTerm=$2&Location=$3&Rating=$4&Keyword=$5     
        RewriteRule    ^search-result/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$    search-result.php?BtnSearch=$1&SearchTerm=$2&Location=$3   
        RewriteRule    ^search-result/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$    search-result.php?BtnSearch=$1&SearchTerm=$2 
        RewriteRule    ^special-deal/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?$    special-deal.php?BtnSearch=$1&SearchTerm=$2&Location=$3&Rating=$4&Keyword=$5


</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A2592000
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^/data/*.php">
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```